# MappingNotFoundException when running queries in IntelliJ Hibernate console

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run HQL queries in IntelliJ's Hibernate Console. I've added the datasource to the Data Sources view and added my `hibernate.cfg.xml` to the Hibernate facet such that in appears in the Persistence view. The content of `hibernate.cfg.xml` is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mmanager</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="dialect">com.puca.core.util.db.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="com/puca/messagemanager/api/model/XmlApiDlrMapping.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The `.hbm.xml` is shown in green, whereas if I change it to a file that doesn't exist it is shown in red, so it seems that IntelliJ can find it. However, if I run a simple query in the console like:

```
from XmlApiDlrMapping xmlApiDlrMapping 
where xmlApiDlrMapping.retries = 5
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/puca/messagemanager/api/model/XmlApiDlrMapping.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1587)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
```

I'm using IntelliJ 10.5.4.

Comment: make sure you do not have any typo for the path.

Comment: @vinodn I've made sure the path is correct

Comment: Try moving xml to another location and add it to your class path manually.. Probably the xml is not being copied to classes directory.
or.. Look into your classes output folder and check if the xml is present. Just trying to figure out which class loader you are using.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says in the error message. The mapping XML file is missing:

`com/puca/messagemanager/api/model/XmlApiDlrMapping.hbm.xml`

These files are used to map table columns to your entity class fields.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-mapping

Comment: The mapping file is not missing. The path to the file `<mapping resource="com/puca/messagemanager/api/model/XmlApiDlrMapping.hbm.xml"/>` is shown in green, indicating that it's valid, whereas if I change the path such that it references a non-existent file, it's shown in red.

Comment: Green or not, did you check that the file is there - i.e. on the filesystem?

Comment: Then I'd suggest IntelliJ is messing up the class path, or it's already messed up. Sorry if I can't be of any more help - not a fan of IntelliJ.

Comment: Are you sure this file is copied to the output/classpath on compilation? See Settings | Compiler | Resource Patterns.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have `?*.xml;` in the resource patters, so I guess it should be copied to the output

Comment: @Don, can you send a sample project to JetBrains support?