# test Hibernate queries

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a simple way to test Hibernate HQL criteria queries. I've tried using IntelliJ's Hibernate Console support, but I've [run into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294318/mappingnotfoundexception-when-running-queries-in-intellij-hibernate-console).

Is there a standalone tool that provides a simple way to test HQL queries? A simple console program that creates the session factory and executes a query passed as an argument would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [H2](http://www.h2database.com) (JDBC in-memory) database, and [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) for your container, to create a container and context that will execute hibernate queries in the unit-test phase of your build (or from JUnit).

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `JUnit` approch.

Answer (score 0):

Using a console would be my first choice for just playing with HQL (eg [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) for eclipse).  But if that doesn't work, I would just use JUnit.  My team uses that strategy to test the HQL queries that we use in production code, and occasionally to help write queries in the first place.

The test setup involves setting up an in-memory database (we use [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), but there's others).  Insert data either with Hibernate or with raw SQL.  Then configure a Hibernate SessionFactory to connect to it, and run your HQL.

We also use this to test other kinds of Hibernate settings or behaviors, and has the side benefit of being a full test suite on Hibernate for our purposes so that we can upgrade and have confidence that nothing we need has changed in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's possible to have such a tool as a separate app, you'll need to specify a hibernate configuration (which might be in Spring Context), and it should be able to find the classes and their HBM files. Moreover you might use different UserTypes or anything like that from other JARs, so I wouldn't even search for it.

For me the best tool is a unit testing framework + debugging facilities of your IDE - you can just stop at some point where you have a session created and do whatever you want in this mode. In IntelliJ for instance, aside of usual expressions, you can put code fragments during debugging which might help you with Criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had to do this kind of work I used [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to test my data access layer in which I was using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate